# Eclipse SDK Manager File not found

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm setting up a new eclipse environment.  I just installed the ADT plugin and restarted eclipse as Administrator.  When I try to open the SDK Manager via Window -> Android SDK Manager, I see the following in the Console:

[image: SDK Manager Error]

I'm not sure what's causing the [Encoding Issue]x86_64 error.  I'm assuming I need to go and manually edit some configuration file by hand so that the path doesn't contain the bad character, but I'm not sure which file/where.  Does anyone know what file I need to edit to fix this, or possibly some alternative fix?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android (On left list) -> SDK Location (On Right box)

Put the correct location of your SDK's folder

Comment: Try running the SDK Manager directly, outside Eclipse.
Are you on Windows? If yes, its a simple exe that you have to execute. If this don't work, your SDK folder is broken

Comment: Just uninstalled the SDK and reinstalled directly under C:\.  Still shows that goofy [?] symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If You downloaded all required Software correct, maybe You forgot to set the SDK Location in Eclipse. Go to Windows-->Preferences-->Android. On the top of the window is a field SDK-Location. There you should browse to your SDK location, after You have done this, press Apply-Button.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Android SDK install directory (`...\Android\android-sdk`) there's a tools directory containing a file called android.bat.  The line

```
for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
```

is setting `swt_path` to the invalid string `lib\♀x86_64`.

You can see this by removing the `@echo off` command on the first line and adding this line right after the `for /f...` command.

```
echo %swt_path%
```

My fix was to hardcode the correct path right after the `for \f...` command, like so

```
set swt_path=lib\x86_64
```

I'm assuming this is a bug with the bat file itself (not using proper encoding, or something of that nature).

Answer (score 0):

in windows sometimes you can have problems with reaching the file.maybe you can switch the eclipse folder's place for example to desktop.and reinstall the sdk for eclipse again.we solved a problem like that on my friends computer by following this way